# Problem in response from servlet output stream

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, download

In my Java Based Web application, I am trying to write some files in a ZIP file and I want to prompt the user to download/cancel/save. The time when the download dialog box opens and if I click on cancel, after then if I try to access any links in my application then the dialog box opens again. Here's my code snippet.

```
private void sendResponse(byte[] buf, File tempFile) throws IOException {
    long length = tempFile.length();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    String disposition = "attachment; fileName=search_download.zip";
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = null;
    InputStream in = null; 
    try {
        if (buf != null) {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
            servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType("application/zip");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition);
            while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(buf)) != -1)) {
                servletOutputStream.write(buf, 0, (int) length);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (servletOutputStream != null) {
            servletOutputStream.close();
        }
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (tempFile != null) {
            tempFile.delete();
        }
    }
    context.responseComplete();
}
```

Also once I click on save/Open, its working as expected. I hope the problem in clearing the response object. Please help me in providing some solutions.

**EDIT**
downloadSelected Method

```
      public void downloadSelected() throws IOException {

    List<NodeRef> list = init();
    StringBuffer errors = new StringBuffer("");
    ZipOutputStream out = null;

    File tempFile = null;
    byte[] buf = null;
    try {
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            tempFile = TempFileProvider.createTempFile(TEMP_FILE_PREFIX, TEMP_FILE_SUFFIX_ZIP);
            out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile)));
            buf = writeIntoZip(list,out);
            sendResponse(buf,tempFile);
        } else {
            errors.append("No Items Selected for Download");
            this.errorMessage = errors.toString();
        }
    } 
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Cancelled");
    }       
}
```

Write into Zip method:

```
private byte[] writeIntoZip(List<NodeRef> list,ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    String downloadUrl = "";
    InputStream bis = null;
    Node node = null;
    String nodeName = "";
    byte[] buf = null;
    Map<String,Integer> contents = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    ContentReader reader = null;
    for (NodeRef nodeRef : list) {
        try {
            node = new Node(nodeRef);
            nodeName = node.getName();
            reader = Repository.getServiceRegistry(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getContentService().getReader(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(reader.getContentInputStream());
            if (bis != null) {
                contents = setFiles(contents,nodeName);
                nodeName = getUniqueFileName(contents, nodeName);
                buf = new byte[4 * 1024];
                buf = writeOutputStream(bis).toByteArray();
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(nodeName));
                out.write(buf);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
    if(out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Thanks,
Jeya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm admittedly not sure of the root cause of this problem. This behaviour is not explainable based on the code posted as far. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would definitely help more. But I spot several potential causes of this problem. Perhaps fixing one or all of them will fix the concrete problem.

1. You've assigned JSF's `FacesContext` as a property of the bean. This is **bad** and definitely if it's a bean with a broader scope than the request scope. It should *always* be obtained inside the local method scope by `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()`. It's returns namely a thread local variable and should never be shared among other requests. Perhaps you've put the bean in the session scope and a dangling `response` object of the previous request with the headers already set will be reused.
2. You are not catching the `IOException` on `close()` methods. If the client cancels the download, then the `servletOutputStream.close()` will throw an `IOException` indicating that the client has aborted the response. In your case, the `in` won't be closed anymore and the `tempFile` won't be deleted anymore and the JSF response won't be completed anymore. You should also catch the `close()` and log/ignore the exception so that you can ensure that the `finally` finishes its job. Perhaps the presence of `tempFile` has consequences for your future POST actions.
3. You are using `<h:commandLink>` instead of `<h:outputLink>` or `<h:link>` or plain `<a>` for page-to-page navigation. This uses POST instead of GET which is **bad** for user experience and SEO. You should use GET links instead of POST links. See also [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions Balusc. You've helped me many time and also now. Thanks a lot. Also I have tried with the options as you've mentioned. I debugged my code and its going fine into finally method without any exception and made sure that the Manage bean scope is request. I've edited my whole code for the reference. Please lemme know any mistake I Did.